# mzero on pattern matching

Tags: haskell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pattern matching variables in a case statement in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479116/pattern-matching-variables-in-a-case-statement-in-haskell)

I have the following simplified code (the actual code does implement something meaningful
):

```
import Data.Char
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative

testA :: [Int] -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
testA [] _       = Nothing
testA _  Nothing = Nothing
testA (x:xs) v = case x of
  1         -> (+) <$> v <*> return x
  otherwise -> testA xs v

testB :: (MonadPlus m, Applicative m) => [Int] -> m Int -> m Int
testB [] _     = mzero
testB _  mzero = mzero
testB (x:xs) v = case x of
  1         -> (+) <$> v <*> return x
  otherwise -> testB xs v

main = do
  let xpto = testA [1,2,3,1,5] (Just 5)
  print xpto
  let ypto = testB [1,2,3,1,5] (Just 5)
  print ypto
```

It is my understanding that testA and testB should behave the same when feed with the Maybe Monad, meaning that mzero should translate to Nothing.

However, in test B ghc actually gives a warning:

```
Pattern match(es) are overlapped
In an equation for `testB': testB (x : xs) v = ..
```

And the output is different:

```
Just 6 (correct)
Just 5 (incorrect)
```

I am not sure what I might be missing, why isn't the mzero equivalent to nothing in the pattern match?

Comment: You're right... I actually saw that explanation in RWH, but I thought it only applied to case. The actual solution is to use guards, and eliminate the mzero.